# How to import JSON from a local file in Ionic4

Tags: javascript, json, ionic4

This is is a simple bit of script from a html doc, would it be the same insertion of script in an ionic 4 document?

```html
<script>
  let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = "jsonPractice.json";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      var menuItems = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      buildItem(menuItems);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  function buildItem(items) {
    var output = "",
      selectedID = localStorage.getItem("selected");

    items.forEach(function(item) {
      if (selectedID == item.id) {
        output = "<li class='item'>" +
          "<h3>" + item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + "</h3>" +
          "<img class='pic' src=assets/images/" + item.photo + " />" +
          "<p>age: " + item.age + "</p>" +
          "<p>status: " + item.status + "</p>" +
          "<p>how We Met: " + item.howWeMet + "</p>" +
          "</li>";
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = output;
  }
</script>
```

I know ionic is different and am still learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Copy JSON file inside the assets folder. Import HTTP Client inside you component or implement a service with HTTP Client imported. You can now use Get method to read the JSON file. Example:

```
    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
    loadJson() {
      this._http.get('./assets/jsonfilename.json').subscribe(
       data => console.log(data)
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic 4 with typescript 3+ you can do it this way:

1. add support for json import as a module for your app: for that find tsconfig.json file in your root of the app and ensure this properties are set:

> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "resolveJsonModule": true,
>     "esModuleInterop": true  
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Make sure you move your json into assets folder as it is a static asset. Then inside your ts file you can do:

> import myJsonData from './assets/jsonfilename.json';

Then you can work with myJsonData which will be your json.